# Modal showing individual items from paged AJAX list results, only works on first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, getuikit

I have an index with a list of 100+ members *(for example)* with an AJAX'd pagination showing 20/page. The pagination and the list updates fine.

**The issue:**

The modal works fine as well *but only for the first page*. If I turn off the 'remote: true', the modal works on every page.

**The code so far:**

*controller/members_controller.rb*

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @members = Member.all.page(params[:page]).per(20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

*views/members/index.html.erb*

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>modal button</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="members">
    <%= render @members %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= paginate @members, window: 2, remote: true %>
```

*views/members/index.js.erb*

```
$('#paginator').html('<%= j paginate @members %>');
$('#members').html('<%= j render partial: @members %>');
```

*views/members/_member.html.erb*

```
<tr>
  <td><%= member.name %></td>
  <td><button uk-toggle="target: <%= "#modal-member-#{member.id}" %>">OK</button></td>
</tr>

<div id="<%= "modal-member-#{member.id}" %>" uk-modal>
  <p>Some more random infos</p>
</div>
```

If you need any more info, do ask, please. I'm using UIkit3 framework.

Comment: `params[:page] ||= 1` add this line of code as first line in controller and lets try again and let me know if its working or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    params[:page] ||= 1 #add this on line of code
    @members = Member.all.page(params[:page]).per(20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

end

changes in `index.js.erb` i think you don't need to pass `remote:true` in js file

```
$('#paginator').html('<%= j paginate(@members, remote: true) %>');
$('#members').html('<%= j(render partial: @members) %>');
```

Comment: Adding the line in the controller doesn't do the trick. As for the 'remote: true' in the js file, if I don't add them, at some point it loads the page by adding the parameter in the link.

Comment: Ok, the 'remote:true' part in the js works without it now. Thanks. Still hoping I get that modal thing to work.

Comment: feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. And let me know for further guidance

Comment: I will upvote the solution. I have none so far. Thanks for trying tho. :)

Comment: @dugzino could you tell me what issue are you facing with modal in detail.?

Comment: I'm on an index that has more than 1 page that uses an Ajaxed pagination (kaminari) system. The index displays a list of members with a button when clicked on it shows a modal. The modal works perfectly fine as long as I'm on the first page of that index. Every other pages are not working whilst using the Ajaxed pagination. If I turn the Ajax off (to let it display ?page=* on the link) then the modal works on every page.

Comment: @dugzino can you share your modal code of button on that click modal is being opened?